# how to change the startup apple logo on OS 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac, boot

I have tried some applications that replace the apple logo. These worked on older OS's on 10.9 it changed the Apple logo but at bootup you got the apple logo for a second.

My understanding is that there are really 3 to 4 apple logo's that show up dairying the starting process.

1. if you have file vault
2. enabled just after boot
3. just before loading the loginWindow process